# How does Java determine uniqueness of Hashmap key?

Tags: java

I want to maintain a list of objects such that each object in the list is unique.Also I want to retrieve it at one point. Objects are in thousands and I can't modify their source to add a unique id. Also hascodes are unreliable.

My approach was to utilize the key uniqueness of a map. 
Say a maintain a map like :

`HashMap<Object,int> uniqueObjectMap`.

I will add object to map with as a key and set a random int as value. But how does java determine if the object is unique when used as a key ?

Say,

```
List listOne;
List listTwo;
Object o = new Object;
listOne.add(o);
listTwo.add(o);

uniqueObjectMap.put(listOne.get(0),randomInt()); // -- > line 1
uniqueObjectMap.put(listTw0.get(0),randomInt());  // --> line 2
```

Will line 2 give an unique key violation error since both are referring to the same object o ?

**Edit**

So if will `unqiueObjectMap.containsKey(listTwo.get(0))` return true ? How are objects determined to be equal here ? Is a field by field comparison done ? Can I rely on this to make sure only one copy of ANY type of object is maintained in the map as key ?

Comment: IF you want to maintain a list of objects such that each object in the list is unique, why not use a LinkedHashset or HashSet? because set guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: Have you looked at the LinkedHashSet class? It's a Set that keeps the order in which you inserted the entries, like a List, but automatically removes duplicates, like a Set.

Answer (score 3):

> Will line 2 give an unique key violation error since both are referring to the same object o ?

- **No**. If a key is found to be already present, then *its value will be overwritten with the new one*.

Next, HashMap has a separate `hash()` method which *Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode (of key objects), which  defends against poor quality hash functions.*

Comment: So `objectMap.containsKey(o)` will give true ? How reliable is this ? What determines that the object is equal to key ? Is a field by field comparision done ?

Comment: @Aneesh HashMap will first do a lookup based on hash.  HashMap will first do a lookup based on `hashCode()`, and will then check for equality using `equals(Object)` (possibly through several objects if multiple different keys have the same hash)

Comment: @Aneesh - No. Field by field comparison is not done. instead, hashCode of the key is used.

Answer (score 2):

It does so by calling the `Object`'s `hashcode()` function.

The default implementation is roughly equivalent to the object's unique identifier (much like a memory address); however, there are objects that are compare-by-value.  If dealing with a compare-by-value object, `hashcode()` will be overridden to compute a number based on the values, such that two identical values yield the same `hashcode()` number.

As for the collection items that are hash based, the `put(...)` operation is fine with putting something **over** the original location.  In short, if two objects yeild the same `hashcode()` and a positive `equals(...)` result, then operations will assume that they are for all practical purposes the same object.  Thus, put may replace the old with the new, or do nothing, as the object is considered the same.

It may not store two copies in the same "place" as it makes no sense to store two copies at the same location.  Thus, sets will only contain one copy, as will map keys; however, lists will possibly contain two copies, depending on how you added the second copy.

Comment: How reliable is hashCode() function to determine uniqueness? Could there be cases where two same objects (or different objects) resulting in same hashcode ?

Comment: @Aneesh If using the default (compare by instance), it is rather accurate; however, even when it does collide, all the algorithims that use `hashcode()` for quick comparison use `equals(...)` for slower comparison in the event of a collision.  As such, you should take extra care that any overriding implementations of `equals(...)` also overrides `hashcode()` in a coherent, consistent, coordinated manner.

Answer (score 2):

**How are objects determined to be equal here ?** 
By using equals and Hashcode function of Object class.

**Is a field by field comparison done ?**
No, if you dont implement equals and hashcode, java will compare the references of your objects.

**Can I rely on this to make sure only one copy of ANY type of object is maintained in the map as key ?**
No.

Using a `Set` is a better approch than using `Map` because it removes duplicates by his own, but in this case it wont work either because `Set` determinates duplicates the same way like a `Map` does it with Keys.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to maintain a list of unique objects ?

Comment: @Aneesh Have you looked into LinkedHashset or HashSet??

Comment: @codeMan Two problems with those two classes : 1. Comparision for uniqueness isn't reliable just like hashmaps 2. No way to get an object directly without iterating through the whole thing(which I can't do in my requirements)

Comment: @Aneesh How do your objects look like?

Comment: @kai Object can be an instance of any of the 1000 plus classes I have.This also makes it unfeasible to add some unique key to all these classes ( too many classes to modify) or overide hashcode.

Comment: So if you cannot modify the objects you can only work with the references here. If you can modify the data i would suggest to write a superclass which got a uniqe id field and compare this id in equals function and use it as hashcode.

Comment: I Can only work with references. Not feasible to modify the source or subclass a superclass.

Comment: @Aneesh does these objects have .equals() method overridden in them?

Comment: Then, I think its near to impossible to come up with a solution with out modifying the classes for these objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you will refer to `same` then it ll `not throw an error` because when `HashMap get same key` then it's related value will be `overwrite`.

If the same key is exist in `HashMap` then it will be `overwritten`.

if you want to check if the key or value is already exist or not then you can use:

`containsKey()` and `containsValue()`.

ex :

`hashMap.containsKey(0);`

this will return `true` if the key named `0` is already exist otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

By getting hashcode value using `hash(key.hashCode())`

```
HashMap has an inner class Entry with attributes 
      final K key;
      V value;
      Entry<K ,V> next;
      final int hash;
```

Hash value is used to calculate the index in the array for storing Entry object, there might be the scenario where 2 unequal object can have same equal hash value.

Entry objects are stored in linked list form, in case of collision, all entry object with same hash value are stored in same Linkedlist but equal method will test for true equality. In this way, HashMap ensure the uniqueness of keys.